# itrans in description environment

Tags: description, transliteration

I am using the `itrans` package to obtain IAST Romanized Sanskrit.

I want to generate a list of word-meanings using the `description` environment.

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Merriweather}
%
\newcommand{\iast}{\catcode`\^=11
           \catcode`\~=11
           \fontspec[Script=Latin,Mapping=itrans-iast]{Merriweather}}
%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]%
   {\hspace{\labelsep}{\bfseries\iast #1}:}
%
\begin{document}

{\iast mahAbhadrA}\\
{\iast divyA~NgA}\\
{\iast pustakadhR^it}\\

\begin{description}
\item [mahAbhadrA] Greatly auspicious/benign
% \item [divyA~NgA] Having divine limbs
% \item [pustakadhR^it] Holding a book/books
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

I have substantially followed the example in the `itrans` package `README` to get thus far. The first three lines show the correct diacritics.

If the first commented out line in the `description` environment is uncommented, I get the wrong diacrtitics.

If the second commented line is uncommented, I get an error because math-mode is expected.

What should I do?

Comment: I do not know enough about this. I was blindly following what was recommended in the `README` file that appeared after I typed `texdoc itrans`.

Comment: Perhaps they know better, I'll delete my comment

Comment: @daleif:I think your first comment was correct. Perhaps you might want to restore it, if possible. I have given a solution below.

Comment: I don't think deleted comments can be resurrected.

Comment: I could not test as I could not get the font to work on my Linux box

Comment: Sorry. If you have Noto Serif or Noto Sans that might be a suitable substitute.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `README` for `itrans` needs to be updated.

After some experimentation, I have found two ways to workaround this problem. Both solutions have been outlined in the MWE below:

```
% The tilde (~) and hat (^) characters have non-literal meanings in LaTeX.
% The Itrans scheme uses them as literals for Indic transliteration.
% To accomplish this change, one can change each occurrence of 
% ~ with \~{}
% and
% ^ with \^{}
% in the source itrans file using a simple sed filter like
% 
% sed -e 's/~/\\~{}/g' -e 's/\^/\\\^{}/g' <original.tex >modified.tex
% or
% sed -e 's/[\^~]/\\&{}/g' <original.tex >modified.tex
%
% and process the file modified.tex without error using xelatex
% with no extra commands other than the definition of a newfontfamily,
% as shown below. No catcode changes would be required.
%
% However, to avoid the preprocessing step, and use the original file, 
% one could redefine the two catcodes and wrap the original decription 
% environment with a new iast environment and redefined label 
% as shown below. The catcodes would be restored on exiting the 
% iast environment.
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Merriweather}
    \newfontfamily{\romskr}[Script=Latin,Mapping=itrans-iast,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Merriweather}
%
% Redefine tilde and hat as literals.
%
\newcommand{\tildehatliteral}%
    {\catcode`\^=11%
    \catcode`\~=11}
%
% Restore the original LaTeX meanings to tilde and hat.
%
\newcommand{\tildehatrestore}%
    {\catcode`\^=7%
    \catcode`\~=13}
%
% Define a wrapper environment called iast around description 
% to transliterate from Itrans to IAST.
%
\newenvironment{iast}%
    {\tildehatliteral\begin{description}}%
    {\end{description}\tildehatrestore}
%
% Redefine the label to reflect the IAST diacritics
%
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]%
   {\hspace\labelsep\bfseries\romskr{#1}:}
%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%
\begin{document}
%
% Use the newly defined iast environment.
%
\begin{iast}
\item [mahAbhadrA] Greatly auspicious/benign
\item [divyA~NgA] Having divine limbs
\item [pustakadhR^it] Holding a book/books
\end{iast}
%
% Alternatively, use \tildehatliteral and \tildehatrestore 
% explicitly within a standard description environment 
% to get identical output.
% 
\begin{description}
\tildehatliteral
\item [mahAbhadrA] Greatly auspicious/benign
\item [divyA~NgA] Having divine limbs
\item [pustakadhR^it] Holding a book/books
\tildehatrestore
\end{description}
%
\end{document}
```

If anyone knows of a better workaround, please post it here.